# Split a data frame by a factor and remove rows of unequal columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to split columns in a dataframe and place them next to each other based on a single factor column. I would like to take this:

```
   TOD  Value
1  Day   135
2  Day   513
3  Day   567
4  Day   848
5  Day   578
6  Night 145
7  Night 267
8  Night 589
9  Night 258
10 Night 278
11 Night 149
```

and turn it into this:

```
   TOD  Value TOD_2 Value_2
1  Day   135  Night  145
2  Day   513  Night  267
3  Day   567  Night  589
4  Day   848  Night  258
5  Day   578  Night  278
```

The last row (11) needs to be removed so that all columns are of equal length. I can't have 0's or NA's as a 'filler' row. How do I do this? I have code that can accomplish the splitting part, but only if the columns are all equal:

```
df2<- df %>%
  group_split(TOD) %>%
  Map(function(x, y) {names(x) <- paste(names(x), y, sep = "_"); x}, ., 1:length(.)) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

this also works:

```
df2<- do.call(cbind, split(df, df$TOD)) |> 
  setNames(c(names(df), paste0(names(df), "_2")))
```

I need to add something that will remove extra rows if the 'Value_2' column exceeds the number of values in the original 'Value' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base solution:

```
result = split(df, df$TOD)

# truncate to the fewest number of rows
result = lapply(result, head, min(sapply(result, nrow)))

result = do.call(cbind, result)
result
#   Day.TOD Day.Value Night.TOD Night.Value
# 1     Day       135     Night         145
# 2     Day       513     Night         267
# 3     Day       567     Night         589
# 4     Day       848     Night         258
# 5     Day       578     Night         278
```

Comment: This works, any way I can turn it into a 'for' loop?

Comment: Of course--anything can go in a for loop. Without more details it's hard for me to know what's challenging about putting this in a for loop. Like, what are you looping over? I'd suggest asking a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: I figured it out, was having an off day yesterday. Wound up doing this:      ```jj<- mget(ls(pattern = 'Dai15_Dai3_*'))
n = 7
transposed_data = list()
for (i in seq(n)) {
  transposed_data[[i]]<- split(jj[[i]], jj[[i]]$Dai)
  transposed_data[[i]] <- lapply(transposed_data[[i]], head, min(sapply(transposed_data[[i]], nrow)))
  transposed_data[[i]] <- do.call(cbind, transposed_data[[i]])
}  ```

Comment: Here's the next trick, would I be able to then revert the df back to its original layout? With both groups stacked again? After I split them I added a new row of adjusted data and now need to stack them on top of each other again.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to reshape to wide format which could work for most of the cases i.e. length same or not

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cn = match(TOD, unique(TOD)), rn = rowid(TOD)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = cn, values_from= c(TOD, Value)) %>% 
 select(-rn) %>%
 drop_na()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  TOD_1 TOD_2 Value_1 Value_2
  <chr> <chr>   <int>   <int>
1 Day   Night     135     145
2 Day   Night     513     267
3 Day   Night     567     589
4 Day   Night     848     258
5 Day   Night     578     278
```

---

Also, we may use `qpcR:::cbind.na`

```
na.omit(do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, split(df, df$TOD)))
  TOD Value Night.TOD Night.Value
1 Day   135     Night         145
2 Day   513     Night         267
3 Day   567     Night         589
4 Day   848     Night         258
5 Day   578     Night         278
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(TOD = c("Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night"), Value = c(135L, 
513L, 567L, 848L, 578L, 145L, 267L, 589L, 258L, 278L, 149L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: These do run but for some reason they create a DF with just headers and no data...

Comment: @JacksonASwan not clear about the issue.  Are you getting the same output with the data in my post

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Similar to your original attempt:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(TOD) |>
  mutate(ID = row_number()) |>
  group_split() |>
  reduce(full_join, by = "ID", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) |>
  select(TOD_1, TOD_2, Value_1, Value_2) |>
  drop_na()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   TOD_1 TOD_2 Value_1 Value_2
#>   <chr> <chr>   <int>   <int>
#> 1 Day   Night     135     145
#> 2 Day   Night     513     267
#> 3 Day   Night     567     589
#> 4 Day   Night     848     258
#> 5 Day   Night     578     278
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    split(df, ~TOD),
    head, 
    with(df, min(by(TOD, TOD, length)))
  )
)
```

gives

```
  Day.TOD Day.Value Night.TOD Night.Value
1     Day       135     Night         145
2     Day       513     Night         267
3     Day       567     Night         589
4     Day       848     Night         258
5     Day       578     Night         278
```